# Как получить имя и фамилию из аккаунта гугла?

Tags: java, android

Чтобы человек открывает приложение и он пишет "Привет, Лоло Лололошев"

Answer (score 1):

Юзер должен как минимум дать вашему приложению доступ к своим данным. 
Вы можете использовать для этого протоколы OAuth2 или использовать готовые API, к примеру Spring Social. 
После этого, каждый следующий вход будет уже показывать имя фамилию юзера.